# Javascript adaption to current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a java script menu. Everything is working like a charm exept the open sections should adapt automaticly. When there is the class "active" in a specific li element this menu element should be open.

Now always the first li element is open, also when the class changes it is still open.

Can you help me solving this issue?

Demonstration:
https://jsfiddle.net/fj8fywuy/

Thank you in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
  $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
  $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
   $('#nav li a').parent().removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active'); // li tag inside active class
}
  });
  if($(".active").parent().parent().is('#nav')){
    $(".active").next().slideToggle();
  }else{
   $(".active").parents('ul').siblings('a').click();
  }
 $('#nav > li > a:first').click();
});
```

```css
#nav {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
}
#nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    list-style:none;
}
#nav li a:hover, #nav li a.active {
}
#nav li ul {
    display: none; // used to hide sub-menus
     list-style:none;
}
#nav li ul li a {
    padding: 10px 25px;
}

#nav li.sub {
  padding-left: 35px;
}

ul{
  list-style:none;
  
}
.active
{
  background:#c2c2c2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" >Sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 c</a></li>
      <li class="sub"><a href="#" >Sub-sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
      <li class="sub"><a href="#" >Sub-sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 b</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 c</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 d</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 c</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The fiddle and snippet both seem to work..

Comment: Why don't you just toggle based on class `.active` via CSS? That would make your life so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

you have little issue in js i have fixed it and seems everything works fine now.

I have just replaced

```
$('#nav > li > a:first').click();
```

with

```
$('#nav li.active a').click();
```

so this will find active li and open it at start.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
  $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
  $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
   $('#nav li a').parent().removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active'); // li tag inside active class
}
  });
  if($(".active").parent().parent().is('#nav')){
    $(".active").next().slideToggle();
  }else{
   $(".active").parents('ul').siblings('a').click();
  }
 $('#nav li.active a').click();
});
```

```css
#nav {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
}
#nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    list-style:none;
}
#nav li a:hover, #nav li a.active {
}
#nav li ul {
    display: none; // used to hide sub-menus
     list-style:none;
}
#nav li ul li a {
    padding: 10px 25px;
}

#nav li.sub {
  padding-left: 35px;
}

ul{
  list-style:none;
  
}
.active
{
  background:#c2c2c2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" >Sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 c</a></li>
      <li class="sub"><a href="#" >Sub-sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
      <li class="sub"><a href="#" >Sub-sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 b</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 c</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 d</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 c</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```